# How to hide one side shadow effect?

Tags: css

```
<div id="cat"></div>
```

How to box-shadow for left and right side only?
(no shadow of upper lower side)

Comment: If you don't bother to even format your code why would we bother to read it and help you?

Comment: I wrote it but no show!!! strange????

Comment: You might want to take a look at the FAQ on how yo format your questions and your code.

Comment: @Soon Yeoung. To format, you can use the ` at the start and end of small bits  of code.  You can also indent the code four spaces or highlight and click the { } above the textarea.

Comment: I did nothing but now you can see it. seems take a time

Comment: ah! ok... Jason Gennaro!

Answer (score 3):

set the `z-index` of *woof* above *meow* and *grrrr* will show up on top of *hisssss*'s shadow.

Comment: @SoonYeoung - add `position:relative` to both

Answer (score 1):

Here's an overflow hidden approach for one side shadow http://starikovs.com/2011/11/09/css3-one-side-shadow/. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

With this you can do it http://jsfiddle.net/QkXqU/

CSS:

```
div {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px 0px 10px 0px; /*  Use padding on the side where you want to show shadow. Padding amount should be same as shadows blur length. */
}

img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 0px #000000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixum.com/output/nature-q-c-309-249-8.jpg" alt="trees" />
</div>
```